When imputing a numeric column, does it matter if the imputed value is impossible?
Suppose we have a table with flight data, and one of the numeric columns denotes airline ID. The same airline appears many times in the table, so this column can potentially have predictive value.
Some of the data in this column is missing. Does it make sense to fill in the missing cells with the mean of the values?
Clearly the mean of this column does not denote anything in the real world, and furthermore it is likely not an integer, and hence an impossible value for this column.
However, perhaps it makes sense to use this value for machine-learning purposes, in that, to a dumb machine learning algorithm, it is a non-conspicuous filler that is close enough to real data points, it doesn't break the algorithm, and it allows the rest of the values in the row to be used for learning purposes, rather than discarded.
When imputing a numeric column, must the imputed value be a possible value? Must it be a meaningful value?

Airline ID is not really a numeric variable. Sure, it may be a number but it is much more like phone numbers, social security numbers, and so on. No information would be lost if it were changed to an alphabetic code or the name of the airline. The mean of any of these variables would be meaningless.
Depending on how airline IDs are assigned, there may be some information in the numbers (e.g. perhaps the first digits indicate country) and this might be useful. But, in general, you should treat it as a categorical variable.
For such variables, the multiple imputations might include other codes that already exist. For instance, you might impute the code for  "American" in some imputations and "United" in other imputations.

This doesn't really answer my question. I already mentioned that the mean is meaningless. The question is: so what if it's meaningless? Does it really matter, for the purpose of obtaining a good prediction based on a whole slew of columns, only one of which is Airline ID? Also, you are assuming information about the airline ID that I didn't specify in my question. There is no inherent way of extracting the identity of the airline from the Airline ID. It's just an arbitrary number. However, it may still have a predictive value.

Yes, it really does matter. And if you can't get airline from airline ID, then that's another problem.

Would it be better to impute the most frequent value rather than the mean? If so, why?

It would be better to do multiple imputation with the methods for categorical variables. Just putting in the most frequent value is not recommended. And, even for a truly numerica variable, mean imputation is not recommended.

Missing here is just another value unless you have ways to predict missing statistically, So I think the most you can do is to assign a distinct numeric identifier not otherwise used. Presumably the identifiers are essentially categories that happen to be coded as integers. How helpful that is predictively or analytically is an open question.
